# attribute error when downloading youtube video with pytube

Tags: python-3.x, download, attributeerror, pytube

i have been using python for a while now, and i decided to use pytube to download videos from Youtube, but when i try downloading videos it gives an attribute error.

```
import pytube
from pytube import *


def run():
try:
    down_dir = "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/python projects/youtube_video_installer"
    video_link = input("enter video url")
    res_selected = input("enter required res")
    youtube = YouTube(video_link)
    title = youtube.title
    print("Now downloading,  " + str(title))

    video = youtube.streams.get_by_resolution(res_selected)
    # file_size = "FileSize : " + str(round(video.filesize / (1024 * 1024))) + "MB"

    print(title)

    if down_dir is not None:
        video.download(output_path=down_dir, filename=str(title))
    else:
        video.download()
    print("Download complete, " + str(title))

except Exception as e:
    print("ErrorDownloadVideo  |  " + str(video_link))


run()
```

when i set video = youtube.streams.first()
it works but whenever I specify a video by using .get_by_itag or .get_by_resolution it gives me this error

```
   File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/python projects/youtube_video_installer/console.py", line 31, in          <module>
     run()
   File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/python projects/youtube_video_installer/console.py", line 22, in run
     video.download(output_path=down_dir, filename=str(title))
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'
```

Comment: Try to do `pip uninstall pytube` and then `pip install pytube3`

Comment: No need to change code though

Comment: I have I am using pytube 3